# How to combine minmax function with vh in css grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to set one rows height in mobile view to maximum of 670px and below that minimum of 100vh, but when I write it like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: $bp-mobile) {
    grid-template-rows: minmax(100vh, 67rem) repeat(7, max-content);
  }
```

It always expands me first row to 100vh if viewport height equals 1000px my row has getting height of 1000px. How to combine `vh` below that specific maximum height `670px` to be always `100vh` and over `670px` to lock this row to `670px` of height?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  border: 2px solid red;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(100vh, 67rem) 1fr;
}

.test-1 {
  background-color: orangered;
}
.test-2 {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 30rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test-1">1</div>
  <div class="test-2">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `max-height` like below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  border: 2px solid red;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.test-1 {
  background-color: orangered;
  height:100vh;
  max-height:67rem;
}
.test-2 {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 30rem;
}


html {
  font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test-1">1</div>
  <div class="test-2">2</div>
</div>
```